# Repeater with paging through ObjectDataSource

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is it possible to implement custom paging for repeater using ObjectDataSource's:

```
EnablePaging="true" 
MaximumRowsParameterName="maximumRows" 
StartRowIndexParameterName="startRowIndex" 
SelectCountMethod="TotalNumberOfProducts">
```

Or I must set all values in code behind and pass the to ObjectDataSource's parameters:

```
<SelectParameters>
  <asp:Parameter Name="startRowIndex" DbType="Int32" DefaultValue="0" />
  <asp:Parameter Name="maximumRows" DbType="Int32" DefaultValue="10" />
</SelectParameters>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As repeater does not support paging and you can't achevie this using Objectdatasource...

 but if you want to do paging, you have to handle at code level...

 I did paging for datalist at code level as datalist also not support paging...

 If you need code I can provide you....
Call bindRpt method when you want to bind data to repeater, note: this example handle paging next,back,last,first button.... if anything not clear, plz let me know

```
private void BindRpt()
{
    PagedDataSource ObjPds;
    ObjPds = DoPagging((DataTable)ViewState["dtblProducts"]);
    dlProducts.DataSourceID = "";
    dlProducts.DataSource = ObjPds;
    dlProducts.DataBind();
}
protected PagedDataSource DoPagging(DataTable dt)
{
    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        lblNoRecord.Visible = false;
        pnlNavigation.Visible = true;
        pnlTopNavigation.Visible = true;
    }
    else
    {
        lblNoRecord.Visible = true;
        pnlNavigation.Visible = false;
        pnlTopNavigation.Visible = false;
    }
    PagedDataSource ObjPagDataSource = new PagedDataSource(); //'declares the paged data source
    ObjPagDataSource.DataSource = dt.DefaultView;

    ObjPagDataSource.AllowPaging = true;
    ObjPagDataSource.PageSize = PgSize;
    if (hdfPageIndex.Value == "SetLastPageIndex")
    {
        CurrentPageIndx = ObjPagDataSource.PageCount - 1;
        ObjPagDataSource.CurrentPageIndex = ObjPagDataSource.PageCount - 1;
    }
    else
    {
        ObjPagDataSource.CurrentPageIndex = CurrentPageIndx; 
    }

    if (ObjPagDataSource.PageCount > 1)
    {
        if (ObjPagDataSource.IsFirstPage == true)
        {
            ibtnLast.Enabled = true;
            ibtnFirst.Enabled = false;
            ibtnPrevious.Enabled = false;  
            ibtnNext.Enabled = true;

            ibtnLastTop.Enabled = true;
            ibtnFirstTop.Enabled = false;
            ibtnPreviousTop.Enabled = false;
            ibtnNextTop.Enabled = true;
        }
        else if (ObjPagDataSource.IsLastPage == true)
        {
            ibtnFirst.Enabled = true;
            ibtnLast.Enabled = false;
            ibtnNext.Enabled = false;
            ibtnPrevious.Enabled = true;

            ibtnFirstTop.Enabled = true;
            ibtnLastTop.Enabled = false;
            ibtnNextTop.Enabled = false;
            ibtnPreviousTop.Enabled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            ibtnFirst.Enabled = true;
            ibtnPrevious.Enabled = true;
            ibtnNext.Enabled = true;
            ibtnLast.Enabled = true;

            ibtnFirstTop.Enabled = true;
            ibtnPreviousTop.Enabled = true;
            ibtnNextTop.Enabled = true;
            ibtnLastTop.Enabled = true;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        ibtnFirst.Enabled = false;
        ibtnLast.Enabled = false;
        ibtnPrevious.Enabled = false;
        ibtnNext.Enabled = false;

        ibtnFirstTop.Enabled = false;
        ibtnLastTop.Enabled = false;
        ibtnPreviousTop.Enabled = false;
        ibtnNextTop.Enabled = false;
    }

    return ObjPagDataSource;
}

public int CurrentPageIndx
{
    get
    {
        System.Object o = this.ViewState["_CurrentPageIndx"];
        if (o == null)
            return 0;
        else
            return Convert.ToInt32(o);
    }
    set
    {
        ViewState["_CurrentPageIndx"] = value;
    }
}

protected void ibtnFirst_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    hdfPageIndex.Value = "";
    CurrentPageIndx = 0;
    BindRpt();
}
protected void ibtnPrevious_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    hdfPageIndex.Value = "";
    CurrentPageIndx = CurrentPageIndx - 1;
    BindRpt();
}
protected void ibtnNext_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    hdfPageIndex.Value = "";
    CurrentPageIndx = CurrentPageIndx + 1;
    BindRpt();
}
protected void ibtnLast_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    hdfPageIndex.Value = "SetLastPageIndex";
    BindRpt();
}
```

Comment: Yes, please do I'll appreciate it.

Comment: If i am not mistaken this solution does paging on presentation layer and not on data access level, right?

Comment: yes, you are right, if you want to do paging in data access level, best is do in Stored Procedure level... :)